# Can I create an onclick event in PHP?  

Tags: php, events, click

Can I create an onclick event in PHP?

When the user clicks a button, a string value must change.  Do I have to use JavaScript to do this?

Does PHP support the onclick event?  Can I create variables in PHP?

Comment: *"Do I have to use JavaScripts?"* Yes. *"Do php support on click event?"* No. *"Can we create variables in php?"* Yes. PHP runs on the server side and is just producing the output for the client. It cannot interact with anything on the client side.

Comment: mean i have to understand php first but can i create variables in php?

Comment: I would say every programming language has the concept of variables ;) (but maybe you mean something different with this then I do) And yes, of course you have to understand the tools you are using. Variables in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php You should read a tutorial first: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

Answer (score 5):

In a typical set up:

PHP will run on a server, generate some content and then pass it to the browser.

PHP will not run inside a browser so it cannot handle a click event directly, (client-side) JavaScript can (as could Flash, Java, Silverlight, etc if the button was a Flash/Java/Silverlight/etc button respectively).

A click on a regular form submit button or link will cause the browser to make a new HTTP request to the server and load a new page. PHP can respond with new content then.

If you were building a GUI [directly in PHP](http://gtk.php.net/), which doesn't involve using a web browser, then [click events can be handled directly](http://gtk.php.net/manual/en/gtk.gtkbutton.signal.clicked.php).

Comment: Can we create variables in php?

Comment: Yes, we can create variables in php :)

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to create an onclick event in php...

Not directly. Not within the browser. The only thing you can do is have PHP output JavaScript code that gets executed when the generated page was served to and evaluated by the browser. For your scenario, make sure you understand [serverside coding vs clientside coding](http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/923111/Client-side-Versus-Server-side-Coding---Part-1.htm)

> I am new in using Dreamweaver..

Get a [decent editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166/any-good-php-ide-preferably-free-or-cheap) instead. Dreamweaver is for designers, not developers.

> I want that whenever i click a button a string value must change i-e Do I have to use JavaScripts?

Yes. Register the onClick event via JavaScript in the [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/). Then either embed the logic for the string transformation in JavaScript or pass the original string value via Ajax to a PHP script and have the PHP script return the transformed value. Replace the original string in the browser's DOM with that value.

> Do php support on click event?

[PHP's DOM extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) does not support [DOM Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events) for that matter. But like I already said, your browser is using a JavaScript implementation of DOM so this isnt important to achieve your goal.

> Can we create variables in php?

Yes, you can `$variable = 'foo'`. But if you have to ask that you shouldn't be coding PHP but reading the [PHP Manual Language Reference](http://de.php.net/manual/en/langref.php) and familiarize with the language.

Comment: Thanks alot..please tell me which decent editor i must use...Nestbean ,eclipse,its difficult to configure them to work with php..

Answer (score 1):

PHP is [Server-side programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting)

Javascript is [Client-side programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting)

Onclick events are client-side, meaning they're in the browser. I recommend checking out [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) for your Javascript venture.

Comment: [PHP might not be](http://gtk.php.net/), [JavaScript might not be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript), although it is pretty certain that they are in this instance.

Comment: I thought the gimp toolkit was only for applications, not websites. Completely forgot about it nonetheless :)

Comment: It is, but if you are using it with PHP then you aren't doing server side programming (or, most likely, anything related to websites)

Answer (score 0):

Onclick events are domain of Javascript. So if you want to use this functioning use for example jQuery, library that will help you do it easily.

Comment: Can we create variables in php? i am declaring a variable as instructed at w3school.com but my WAMP server is giving an error that it cannot parse it..

Comment: @Usman: Don't follow the w3school.com stuff. Have a look at the official documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php

Comment: It depend's what do you precisely mean by 'creating variables'. When you construct a form, that gets sent to the server after Submitting it, the user input for that variable is in the $_POST['variable_name'] or $_GET['variable_name'] - depending on which method you used in <form methos="XXX">